# User Input For Loop Python (PyCharm)

Tags: string, for-loop, pycharm

I'm trying to write a program using for loop. I want to ask the user how many strings they would like to make a list. Then with the number they input use it in a for loop to ask them to enter a number of strings one line at a time to populate the items in the list.

And example of the output would be.

```
How many items do you want in your list? 3 
string 1: bread 
string 2: toothpaste 
string 3: eggs
[‘bread’, ‘toothpaste’, ‘eggs’]
```

I am using Pycharm and wouldn't have a clue where to begin.
First time using for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
try:
    ite = int(raw_input("How many items do you want in your list? "))
    stringList = []
    for i in range(ite):
        stringList.append(raw_input("string {0}:".format(i)))
    print(stringList)
except:
    print("Not a Number")
```

Comment: No problem @user2388433. Feel free to accept my answer if it helps. :P :)

Comment: Woked like a charm. 

I did edit a section which allowed the program to begin its output at 1 instead of 0.

Thanks again